# I cant download on other locations outside root!

Tags: 14.04, disk

I have Ubuntu 15.10 running at the moment. I am trying to download a file on my 120GB external drive, but it wont let me. I have no space left on Ubuntu, so I can't download it there.I am using mozilla firefox to download a 5GB file off the internet.
Any suggestions?

Comment: @dani-pi  please limit comments to the comment section.

Comment: if you could please post the path to the external drive, I can give you some commands to download the file using the command line that should be faster than using firefox.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, run the following command to gain ownership and permission over the drive and all external drives:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /media/*
```

---

**Additionally**, you need to go to mozilla settings.

Then, go to Preferences and set Downloads to Always ask me where to save files. So that you can specify the directory.